# Keep data studio (Looker studio) dashboard live owned by users who do not exist anymore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I am looking for a solution to keep looker studio dashboards owned by users, live while the user who created that has left the team.

Comment: That's the purpose of looker studio pro.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is easy, step by step guide by Google:
https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/10835295?visit_id=638218983561139963-2429096097&p=service-account&rd=1#zippy=%2Cin-this-article%2Cuse-cloud-console

*Using a service account instead of an individual user's credentials provides these benefits:
Data sources using service account credentials won't break if the creator leaves your company.*